# Is there a MSG_MORE equivalent in <Winsock.h>?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

In my c++ wrapper for the socket API I use the `send` and `recv` functions as they have (nearly) the same signature. Linux offers a MSG_MORE flag which obtains that a message is not send till all partial messages are sent. Does windows offer the same?
MSDN docu tell me there are just two flags and no MSG_MORE. But I cant believe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WSASend()` and `WSARecv()`, the winsock equivalents of `send()` and `receive()` , have a `MSG_PARTIAL` flag which does the same thing.  In general the winsock functions have more functionality than socket API on Windows.

Comment: Yes I know, thats why im using `<winsock(1).h>`. `WSASend()` has a complete different signature. The lagacy `send()` and `recv()` not.

Comment: If you're writing a wrapper, can you not use the WSA functions -- presumably you're writing the wrapper to hide exactly these differences?

Comment: Yes you're right, but I want to keep it as simple as possible. But it seems not to be possible.